# Selecting a random key from a hash

Tags: perl

How do you select a random hash key? For [my Flash+Perl card game](http://apps.facebook.com/video-preferans/) I'm trying to pick a random card from a hash where keys are: "6 spades", "6 clubs", etc. like this:

```
my $card;
my $i = 0;
for $card (keys %{$user->{HAND}}) {
    last if rand(++$i) < 1;
}
delete $user->{HAND}->{$card};
print "random card: $card\n";
```

I wonder if it's the correct way or if there is a better way.

Comment: Not correct at all. The `$card` in the `for` loop is ["implicitly local to the loop and regains its former value upon exiting the loop"](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlsyn#Foreach_Loops). That is, the `$card` in your print statement is a different variable than the `$card` in the `for` loop.

Comment: Furthermore, The fact that you generate a new number every pass skews the result.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Somewhat more concise:

```
my $random_value = $hash{(keys %hash)[rand keys %hash]};
```

Comment: you inspired me, check out `$random_val_3` in my post.

Comment: nice refp! the art of perl obfuscation!!

Comment: Thank you, I was after my $random_key=(keys %hash)[rand keys %hash];

Answer (score 15):

## Get random value from %hash

---

1. Store the keys of your `%hash` in `@hash_keys`.
2. generate a random number between `0` and the length of `@hash_keys`
3. get the random entry from `@hash_keys`
4. use the acquired key to get your random value from `%hash`

---

**Example snippet**:

```
my %hash = ( 
  'stack' => 'overflow',
  'face'  => 'book',
  'inter' => 'net'
);
```

```
## ALTERNATIVE 1 ##
my @hash_keys    = keys %hash;

my $random_key   = $hash_keys[rand @hash_keys];
my $random_value = $hash{$random_key};
```

```
## ALTERNATIVE 2 ##
my $random_val_2 = (%hash)[1+2*int rand keys%hash]; # TIMTOWTDI
```

```
## ALTERNATIVE 3 ##
my $random_val_3 = [@_=%hash]->[1|rand@_];          # TIMTOWTDI
```

Comment: What does "1|" in the last line do?

Comment: @AlexanderFarber it's a bitwise OR, making sure that we only get odd numbers inside the brackets. `1 | 2 => 3`, `1 | 0 => 1`, `1 | 1 => 1`.  It'll always set the least significant bit in an integer to 1.

Comment: @refp : I find this always returns the same value the first time it's called: `perl -Mstrict -wE 'my %hash = map { $_ => $_ } 1..100; say( (@_=%hash)[1|rand@_] ) for 1..10;'`

Comment: @Zaid Oh of course, thanks for the notice - check out my edit to see a 100% working example.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way (demonstrating how to pick a random element from a list of unknown length):

```
my $cards;
my $chosen;
while ( my $card = each %{$user->{HAND}} ) {
    $chosen = $card if rand(++$cards) < 1;
}
```

Comment: Right, $chosen has to be able to be reset more than once.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is from 2011 and we're in 2022, but this is still the first question/answer that pops up when googling "perl random from hash". I wanted to add an optimized answer.

Hashes are already in a random order. When you create an array based on the keys of the hash, the array is in a random order. So, **assuming you only need to choose one random hash element, not multiple randoms**, you don't need to pick a random item from the array, you can just choose the first element instead.

**How to grab just one random hash element**

1. Store the keys of your %hash in @array.
2. Get the first entry from the @array
3. Use the acquired key to get the value of that key from %hash

**Example snippet:**

```
my %hash = ( 
    'Spanish'  => 'ananas',
    'Danish' => 'ananas',
    'Dutch' => 'ananas',
    'French' => 'ananas',
    'German' => 'ananas',
    'Italian' => 'ananas',
    'Swedish' => 'ananas',
    'English' => 'pineapple',
);

my @languages       = keys %hash;
my $random_language = $languages[0];
my $random_value    = $hash{$random_language};
```