# Why does this random hash value selector always return the same value the first time it's called?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

While trying to understand how [refp's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8547700/133939)  for random hash value selection works, I noticed something strange.

With repeated calls to the following Perl script, I consistently found that the first result returned was the same. The subsequent values returned were random:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my %hash = map { $_ => ord $_ } 'a' .. 'z';

say( (@_=%hash)[1|rand@_] ) for 1 .. 10;       # First value always 119
```

Interestingly, the following does not suffer from this issue:

```
sub random_value { ( @_ )[ 1 | rand @_ ] }

say random_value %hash for 1 .. 10;            # First value is random
```

Removing the references to `@_` also remedies the problem:

```
say( (%hash)[1|rand keys %hash] ) for 1 .. 10; # First value is random
```

This has been tested on Windows (ActivePerl 5.14.2).

On the surface, it looks like setting `@_` has something to do with it, but I'm not sure. Can anyone shed some light on what's happening here?

---

### EDIT

I thought this question was answered until [refp provided an update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8547700/133939). Why does the arrayref form not suffer from the same issue discussed above? :

```
[@_=%hash]->[1|rand@_] for 1 .. 10;            # First value is random
```

Comment: If you want a different sequence each run, you need to seed it first, srand instruction in perl I think.

Comment: Why do I need to `srand` it? I want to produce a random sequence every time and the script outlined in the question is *always* producing the same first value (119). I want to know why the first value is always the same across multiple calls to the script

Comment: You do not need to use `srand`, unless you use a perl version lower than 5.004. See [perldoc -f rand](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rand.html) : `Automatically calls srand unless srand has already been called`

Comment: @Zaid Very curious little problem here. I was also chewing on that random hash value solution a while, but decided I didn't like it because the use of `@_`.

Comment: @ysth, woops! Comment deleted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect there is a race condition where `@_` is not defined in the first loop iteration.

```
say( (@_=%hash)[1|rand@_] ) for 1 .. 10;
```

Will become

```
say( (@_=%hash)[1|rand ()] ) for 1 .. 10;
```

It escapes `warnings` because `@_` is a predeclared variable. As you will notice:

```
say( (my @a=%hash)[1|rand@a] ) for 1 .. 10;
```

Will crash and burn because `@a` is not defined in the postscript.

Update:

```
[@_=%hash]->[1|rand@_] for 1 .. 10;
```

Is not any different. It is still bad practice to use a variable in the same statement that you assign it. The difference, I am guessing, is that the precedence is somewhat altered, so that the assignment is evaluated first.

Comment: @Zaid For a moment there, I thought you had poked a hole in it, since you removed your comment and vote. =P

Comment: This *is* the solution. Calling `rand()` without arguments will return a value between 0 and 1. Combining it with the bitwise or is guaranteed to return 1, which corresponds to `( values %hash )[0]`. It also explains why the other solutions don't suffer from the same symptoms.

Comment: I thought there was a hole because I was expecting `$hash{a}` to be returned as a result of `1|rand()`, until I remembered that hashes don't preserve order :)

Comment: @Zaid I was actually surprised to see that I got the same first value as you, 119. I don't know how hashes are stored or retrieved, but it seems to be consistent.

Comment: Although this does raise a question as to why anyone would sanely want to set `@_` outside a subroutine.

Comment: @zaid Indeed. Too much golfing.

Answer (score 5):

No race condition, or anything to do with whether @_ is "defined" or not, just an order of operations issue.

The indexes for a list slice are evaluated before the list being sliced.  (The documentation doesn't guarantee this one way or the other.)  So on the first iteration, @_ is empty and the argument to rand is 1|0 (= 0).  Historically, rand(0) has behaved like rand(1), though this is now documented as subject to change.  So the index on the first iteration is >= 0 and < 1, and taken to be 0 by the implicit int of indexing.

The array element fetch (`[@_=%hash]->[1|rand@_]`) doesn't suffer a similar problem because it evaluates the index after the array operand.  An array slice (`@{[@_=%hash]}[1|rand@_]`), on the other hand, behaves as the list slice does.

Compare:

List slice:

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'(@_=%hash)[1|rand@_]'
1  <0> enter 
2  <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{
3  <0> pushmark s
4  <$> const[IV 1] s
5  <#> gv[*_] s
6  <1> rv2av[t7] sK/1
7  <1> rand[t8] sK/1
8  <2> bit_or[t9] sK
9  <0> pushmark s
a  <0> pushmark s
b  <#> gv[*hash] s
c  <1> rv2hv[t4] lK/1
d  <0> pushmark s
e  <#> gv[*_] s
f  <1> rv2av[t2] lKRM*/1
g  <2> aassign[t5] lKS/COMMON
h  <2> lslice vK/2
i  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC
-e syntax OK
```

Array slice:

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'@{[@_=%hash]}[1|rand@_]'
1  <0> enter 
2  <;> nextstate(main 2 -e:1) v:{
3  <0> pushmark s
4  <$> const[IV 1] s
5  <#> gv[*_] s
6  <1> rv2av[t8] sK/1
7  <1> rand[t9] sK/1
8  <2> bit_or[t10] sK
9  <0> pushmark s
a  <0> pushmark s
b  <#> gv[*hash] s
c  <1> rv2hv[t4] lK/1
d  <0> pushmark s
e  <#> gv[*_] s
f  <1> rv2av[t2] lKRM*/1
g  <2> aassign[t5] lKS/COMMON
h  <@> anonlist sK*/1
i  <1> rv2av[t6] sKR/1
j  <@> aslice vK
k  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC
-e syntax OK
```

Array element:

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'[@_=%hash]->[1|rand@_]'
1  <0> enter 
2  <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{
3  <0> pushmark s
4  <0> pushmark s
5  <#> gv[*hash] s
6  <1> rv2hv[t4] lK/1
7  <0> pushmark s
8  <#> gv[*_] s
9  <1> rv2av[t2] lKRM*/1
a  <2> aassign[t5] lKS/COMMON
b  <@> anonlist sK*/1
c  <1> rv2av[t10] sKR/1
d  <$> const[IV 1] s
e  <#> gv[*_] s
f  <1> rv2av[t7] sK/1
g  <1> rand[t8] sK/1
h  <2> bit_or[t9] sK
i  <2> aelem vK/2
j  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC
-e syntax OK
```

Comment: Please decipher `O::Concise` output

Comment: @Zaid, Compare the relative position of `rand` and `gv[*hash]`+`rv2hv` (which gets the hash)